# What is strain hardening exponent?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, metallurgy, metals

Hardening leads to a material being more brittle.However I can't understand what is strain hardening or strain hardening exponent.Please explain why hardening leads to brittleness also in this answer itself.I would be happy to get a detailed answer of this.

Comment: Try working copper - it works well when it is soft so you need to anneal it.

Comment: @SolarMike.Explain me the annealing process and well.Would be happy if you elaborate.

Comment: Annealing is heating and allowing to cool. A google search would enlighten you!!!

Comment: Ok but what about the strain hardening and strain hardening exponent@SolarMike

Comment: Hardening does not always reduce the toughness of metals. The 17-4 PH stainless is notorious for having low toughness in the annealed condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some metals like steel go through a large range of hardening, while still ductile and under going plastic yield, before getting to the rupture point.

If you consider the entire area under the strain/stress curve up to fracture point it's called toughness module and in steell it is much larger the resilience (elastic) module.
[image: mild steel stress/ strain graph]

[Source of graph here.](https://www.cmrp.com/blog/faq/analysis-design/exploring-stress-strain-curve-mild-steel.html)

Comment: A fine point of distinction; The "A"  = yield strength , is actually the "yield point" .

Comment: @blacksmith37 I want to know what it physically means.